# Extracting data from Groovy GPathResults

Tags: xml, groovy

I have used Groovy's XmlSlurper to parse some xml into a GPathResult object. However I am unable to extract the "format" and "data" text from the children nodes, it always returns empty text when I invoke the text() method on the individual node, even though I see the text when I look at the GPathResults in debug mode. Please se screenshots

> Unit test with sample xml that will be parsed

[image: Unit test with sample xml that will be parsed]

> Debug view showing GPathResult with correct data

[image: Debug view showing GPathResult with correct data]

> Debug view showing results of getting the "format first ChildNode which should be a String

[image: Debug view showing results of getting the "format first ChildNode which should be a String]

> Debug view after invoking the text() method on the NoChildren node

[image: Debug view after invoking the text() method on the NoChildren node]

Comment: Screenshots instead of code that can be pasted to try out?

Comment: Yes I thought it would be helpful rather than having incomplete code, but if screenshots is frowned upon, next time I will provide the code. Thanks for taking the time to view my question.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong: it.BatchResponse.batchData.response.format  Correct: it.bacthData.response.format

variable "it" is the rootNode and it's name is BatchResponse